# Cypress click() function crashes tests

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to click an `a` link but when I run it with Cypress Open (on any browser) it crashes the test and returns to the Spec screen

`cy.get('ul.navigation li.login a').contains('Sign')`

That find's the link and it's perfect. The test passes and it stays on the results screen. However

`cy.get('ul.navigation li.login a').contains('Sign').click()`

crashes the test.

I'm running Cypress 12.6.0. There is no errors in the console.

Also, running `Cypress Run` just gets stuck and never completes.

EDIT

Additional test is

```
cy.visit('https://www.google.com/');
cy.get('.LX3sZb .gb_p').contains('Gmail').click({force: true});
```

This gets the same result

Comment: The problem is not reproducible from what you've written. What else can you add, is there a redirect or a another tab/window opening?

Comment: No redirect, no new window. It just goes straight back to the spec screen. Nothing in the browser console and nothing in the terminal output other than 200 statuses for the various requests.

Comment: Seems it's limited to your machine, gmail link is working here.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll look into machine setup